# How do I save my account picture in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts

I want to know how to save my account picture.  Its a nice picture but I cannot find a way to save it.  What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think the picture is stored in a binary format and not easily accessible, but you can use the screenshot trick:

Open a windows where your picture is displayed e.g.

```
Control Panel\User Accounts and Family Safety\User Accounts
```

press the PrtScn key, normally above the navigation buttons at the top right of your keyboard.

Press the Windows Key and type `mspaint` to open the Paint program, click `Paste` to paste the screenshot you just did. Now use the `Crop` function to just get your picture.

You can also use any other graphics program to process your screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

In general  the dimension  of the account picture is 1024*768 with jpg format so save the necessary picture.

Once it is saved,Go to Control Panel\User Accounts and Family Safety\User Accounts\Change Your Picture and then chose the one.

Now your profile pictured would be saved.